# Derivative of Trig Function with exponent and chain rule logic

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry, exponential-function

I'm new to calculus and self-learning it, I am having trouble grasping why $\sin^2 5x$ can be rewritten as $(\sin 5x)^2$

I fumble when I try to understand the logic behind it. For example, if I plug in a number for 'sin' I would get a different answer when I plugged it in the original equation and when I plugged it into the rewritten equation. Just trying to understand the logic and the 'why', so I don't go through calculus mindlessly solving equations. Thanks.

Comment: It's notation.  Nothing more.  $\sin^2$ simply means squaring the $\sin$.  It's easier and more convenient than writing $(\sin 5x)^2$.  ... um, but what does this have to do with the title of your post.

Comment: "if I plug in a number for 'sin' I would get a different answer when I plugged it in the original equation and when I plugged it into the rewritten equation. "  What do mean?  What are you talking about.  what equations? what rewriting?

Comment: If $x=\frac \pi 4$ and I plug it into $\sin^2 5x = \sin^2 (5\cdot \frac \pi 4)=\sin^2 \frac {5\pi}4 = (-\frac {\sqrt 2}2)^2 = \frac 12$.  And likewise $(\sin 5x)^2 = (\sin \frac {5\pi}4)^2=(-\frac {\sqrt 2}2)^2 = \frac 12$ as well.  I get know different and do not understand what you mean be getting different answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Math SE!

The question you have is just one of notation. It's pretty standard to write, generally, $[\sin(x)]^n$ as $\sin^n(x)$. The latter notation is probably more common than the former, in fact.

This notation holds broadly for integer values of $n$ except in the case of $n=-1$, when $\sin^{-1}(x)$ denotes $\arcsin(x)$. If you want to write $[\sin(x)]^{-1}$, you could write it as $[\sin(x)]^{-1}$, $\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$, or $\csc(x)$.

So, when you need to take the derivative of $\sin^2(5x)$, it may be a bit easier to think of it as $[\sin(5x)]^2$, then apply the chain rule. They both mean the same thing, it's just easier to recognize the ordering of the function composition: $5x$ is the input to $\sin(\cdot)$, and $\sin(\cdot)$ is the input to $(\cdot)^2$.